Livewire taking too long in rendering select field
I am facing performance issues in Livewire. I am fetching data from a table called "locations." I have implemented the self-join method on this table. "locations" table contain countries, cities, towns, sub-towns, and blocks.
There is a "parent_id" field in the locations table that is storing the ID of the parent for each row.For example, a city has the "parent_id" of a country and vice versa. Currently, I have data for only one country.
I am querying the "locations" table on the basis of cities and then fetching other towns, sub-towns, and blocks for that city.
The problem I am facing is that it is taking around 6 to 7 seconds to display the list of towns along with their sub-towns and blocks after selecting a city.
this is the function for fetching the data
public function updatedSelectedCity($value)
    {
        if ($value != NULL || $value != "") {
            $city = Location::findOrFail($value);
          
            if ($city) {
                $this->lat = $city->lat;
                $this->long = $city->long;
                $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('load-map', ['lat' => $this->lat, 'long' => $this->long]);
            }
            $this->state['city_id'] = $value;
            
            $this->towns =  Location::where('parent_id',$city->id)->where('level',2)->with('child')
            ->where('active', 1)->get();

        } else {
            $this->state['city_id'] = NULL;
            $this->state['town_id'] = NULL;
            $this->selectedTown = NULL;
            $this->state['sub_town_id'] = NULL;
            $this->selectedSubTown = NULL;
            $this->state['f_s_town_id'] = NULL;
            $this->selectedFSTown = NULL;
            $this->sub_towns = NULL;
            $this->fs_towns = NULL;
            $this->towns = NULL;
            $this->lat = NULL;
            $this->long = NULL;
        }
    }

Here I am displaying the data in my livewire view.
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 col-xxl-9">
    <div class="form-group city-group">
        <select id="selectTown" style="width: 251px;!important" class=" js-example-basic-single form-control select-box"  wire:model="selectedTown">
            <option  value="" selected>Select a Town</option>
            @if($towns)
                @foreach($towns as $t)
                    @forelse ($t->child as $sub_town )
                        @forelse ($sub_town->child as $block )
                            <option value="{{$block->id}}">{{$block->name}}, {{$sub_town->name}}, {{$t->name}}</option> 
                        @empty
                            <option value="{{$sub_town->id}}">{{$sub_town->name}}, {{$t->name}}</option>
                        @endforelse
                    @empty
                        <option value="{{$t->id}}">{{$t->name}}</option>
                    @endforelse                                                                      
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

This is my model
class Location extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    function parent()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Location::class, 'parent_id');   
    }
    public function child()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Location::class, 'parent_id');
    }
    public static function generateSlug($title)
    {
        $slug = Str::slug($title);
        if (self::whereSlug($slug)->count() > 0) {
            $count = 1;
            while(self::whereSlug("$slug-$count")->count() > 0)
            {
                $count++;
            }
            return "$slug-$count";
        }
        return $slug;
    }
}

I have checked the query execution time it is taking less than a second. So the problem is not with the query. But It is the forelse's where I am facing speed problem. If I comment the select list part then It work perfectly fine.
<select id="selectTown" style="width: 251px;!important" class=" js-example-basic-single form-control select-box"  wire:model="selectedTown">
    <option  value="" selected>Select a Town</option>
    @if($towns)
        @foreach($towns as $t)
            @forelse ($t->child as $sub_town )
                @forelse ($sub_town->child as $block )
                    <option value="{{$block->id}}">{{$block->name}}, {{$sub_town->name}}, {{$t->name}}</option> 
                @empty
                    <option value="{{$sub_town->id}}">{{$sub_town->name}}, {{$t->name}}</option>
                @endforelse
            @empty
                <option value="{{$t->id}}">{{$t->name}}</option>
            @endforelse                                                                      
        @endforeach
    @endif
</select>


How is performance if you do ->with('child.child')? Also, child is singular, that should really be children, since you're looping over many children, not a single child; name your relationships according to how many rows they can return. You've likely got an N+1 query issue here, where, while looping, you're executing a query on every iteration, which is awful for performance. You're eager loading one level, but nothing beyond that. Or, look into Recursive relationships and see if you can implement that. (Reposting comment for visibility)

Ok, let me try these steps you mention.

I changed  "child" to "children" and then tried ->with('children.children') and it works perfectly fine. Thank you for being so helpful.

Nice! Glad to hear that helped  You should take some time and familiarize yourself with some concepts: "Eager Loading", "N+1 Query", "Recursive Relationships", etc. ->with('children.children') will solve your immediate issue, but if you added another level, you'd have to do ->with('children.children.children') (and so on). There is a way to do this with just ->with('children'), which will load all levels of your hierarchy, but it's complex. Or, name your relationships better; Country::with('provinces.cities.blocks') is much clearer than 'children.children' for example. Cheers!
